# Smallest Width Qualifier is working on emulators but not on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout

I have made two different layouts for one screen and I've put one of it in Smallest Width Qualifier folder(layout/sw-400dp/home_activity.xml) other one is in layout/home_activity.xml.
When I test these layouts on different size emulator it picks the right one but not working when I test on live devices.
Please help me out here!

Comment: how does it work on live devices, and which devices is it?

Comment: it does not work on real device, it is redmi note 5 pro

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your app manifest file.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
      android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
      android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
      android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
      android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
      android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
      android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
      android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Comment: not working sir! and how come it works in emulator and not on real device?

Comment: Please read this as well.https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseSWQuali

Comment: this has 100% nothing to do with the problem in qestion

Comment: Yes it is not working and there is no mention of this on developer site